# How to run SSH command in android programmatically

Tags: android, ssh, jsch

I would like to run a simple SSH command like `ssh -R 80:localhost:1337 serveo.net` , I know there is library [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to do this , but it will not work without username and password . In my case there is no authentication is required . How can I do this ?

**Update**
When I run the command `ssh -R 80:localhost:1337 serveo.net -v`, I get the following output

```
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:07jcXlJ4SkBnyTmaVnmTpXuBiRx2+Q2adxbttO9gt0M
The authenticity of host 'serveo.net (159.89.214.31)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:07jcXlJ4SkBnyTmaVnmTpXuBiRx2+Q2adxbttO9gt0M.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'serveo.net,159.89.214.31' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/paranoid/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to serveo.net ([159.89.214.31]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:80 forwarded to local address localhost:1337
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 80, connect localhost:1337
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
Forwarding HTTP traffic from https://vacuus.serveousercontent.com
```

It also creates `known_hosts` file inside `.ssh` folder. The content of `known_hosts` id following

```
|1|2K3SBFWPCPqI3poBW2X99LiuP8c=|cqCa7m1e23x1P9UpcUuPac+KKI8= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDxYGqSKVwJpQD1F0YIhz+bd5lpl7YesKjtrn1QD1RjQcSj724lJdCwlv4J8PcLuFFtlAA8AbGQju7qWdMN9ihdHvRcWf0tSjZ+bzwYkxaCydq4JnCrbvLJPwLFaqV1NdcOzY2NVLuX5CfY8VTHrps49LnO0QpGaavqrbk+wTWDD9MHklNfJ1zSFpQAkSQnSNSYi/M2J3hX7P0G2R7dsUvNov+UgNKpc4n9+Lq5Vmcqjqo2KhFyHP0NseDLpgjaqGJq2Kvit3QowhqZkK4K77AA65CxZjdDfpjwZSuX075F9vNi0IFpFkGJW9KlrXzI4lIzSAjPZBURhUb8nZSiPuzj
|1|F1SIE4/IIEjZPJfHBIx90xnSjSU=|NKCdGqv3SFcGcAqPLvVfuRXI4Ok= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDxYGqSKVwJpQD1F0YIhz+bd5lpl7YesKjtrn1QD1RjQcSj724lJdCwlv4J8PcLuFFtlAA8AbGQju7qWdMN9ihdHvRcWf0tSjZ+bzwYkxaCydq4JnCrbvLJPwLFaqV1NdcOzY2NVLuX5CfY8VTHrps49LnO0QpGaavqrbk+wTWDD9MHklNfJ1zSFpQAkSQnSNSYi/M2J3hX7P0G2R7dsUvNov+UgNKpc4n9+Lq5Vmcqjqo2KhFyHP0NseDLpgjaqGJq2Kvit3QowhqZkK4K77AA65CxZjdDfpjwZSuX075F9vNi0IFpFkGJW9KlrXzI4lIzSAjPZBURhUb8nZSiPuzj
```

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/connect-from-android-to-ssh-server-without-password
try this

Comment: I would like to do it programmatically

Comment: I would not recommend it but possible https://serverfault.com/a/627909

Comment: [Essentially the same question by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62672518/13317)

Comment: I suggest you run your ssh command with the "-v" flag to print debugging info, then [edit] your question to include the debugging info from a  successful invocation. The whole premise of your question may be incorrect. Ssh may be supplying a username and authenticating without you knowing it.

Comment: Okay, this is an [actual service by serveo](http://serveo.net/blog/remote-access-to-ssh-servers-using-serveo). The actual authentication is keyboard-interactive, but it authenticates without actually prompting the user. I had no trouble connecting & authenticating through jsch, but it couldn't open the remote forward for some reason.

Comment: @Kenster How did u connect ? Could you kindly share the code ? it would be very helpful for me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using serveo through Jsch. The only real "trick" here  seems to be specific to serveo. Serveo won't accept tunnel requests until the session has opened a "shell" or "exec" channel. Serveo uses the shell/exec channel to send status messages to the client. So it's necessary to open a shell or exec channel first, *then* request the remote forward.

The SSH protocol expects the client to supply a user name to login as. The `ssh` command line utility defaults to using the local username if you don't supply one. Jsch similarly defaults to using the value of the [system property "user.name"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). Serveo is somewhat unusual in that it'll accept SSH connections from anyone, so you can use whatever name you like. You can let jsch use its default--assuming that works on android--or you can use a hard-coded name like "x" or "foo".

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JSch.setLogger(new MyLogger());
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            final Session session = jsch.getSession("serveo.net");
            session.setHostKeyRepository(new NoSecurityRepo());
            session.connect();

            // Establish a shell channel to receive messages from serveo
            ChannelShell cc = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel("shell");
            cc.setPty(false);
            cc.setInputStream(System.in);
            cc.setOutputStream(System.out);
            cc.setExtOutputStream(System.err);
            cc.connect();

            // Now open a remote forward
            session.setPortForwardingR(null, 80, "localhost", 3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class MyLogger implements Logger {
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int level) { return true; }
        @Override
        public void log(int level, String message) {
            System.err.printf("%s\t%s%n", level, message);
        }
    }

    /*
     * This implementation of HostKeyRepository is just for demonstration.
     * Every time you use it in production, a kitten dies. Please think of
     * the kittens.
     */
    private static class NoSecurityRepo implements HostKeyRepository {
        @Override
        public int check(String host, byte[] key) { return HostKeyRepository.OK; }
        @Override
        public void add(HostKey hostkey, UserInfo ui) { }
        @Override
        public void remove(String host, String type) { }
        @Override
        public void remove(String host, String type, byte[] key) { }
        @Override
        public String getKnownHostsRepositoryID() { return "NoSecurityRepo"; }
        @Override
        public HostKey[] getHostKey() { return new HostKey[0]; }
        @Override
        public HostKey[] getHostKey(String host, String type) { return new HostKey[0]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , could you kindly tell me , which version of jsch are u using ? I am still getting 'username' is not given exception.I am trying to run this from android .

Comment: Hey , Thanks a lot , I was able to figure that out . Now it is doing exactly what I wanted. You helped me a lot . Good day sir

Comment: Serveo doesn't care what username you use. If you find that you have to supply a username, you can use a hardcoded value like "x" or "foo".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that your ssh command is not using any authentication. Please verify it using verbose out with `ssh -v ...`. I guess it uses `publickey` with your default key `id_rsa` from `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and the server just accepts any key.

If this is the case, you can do the same using jsch.

```
final JSch jSch = new JSch();
jSch.addIdentity(idRsaFile);
final Session newSession = jSch.getSession(null, "serveo.net", 22);
newSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
newSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

session.setUserInfo(new UserInfo() {
        @Override
        public String getPassphrase() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void showMessage(String message) {

        }
    });
newSession.connect(connectTimeout);
```

and then

```
newSession.setPortForwardingR(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But in android where is that file located ?  By the way I have also checked my pc , Inside `.ssh` folder there is a file called `known_hosts` . After running that command that file has value like following 
```
|1|JPsTEjrqseCiLxjSr+00Ad6xGMc=|KKxBd62AgPo0sfeezhh8aGsja20= ssh-rsa
.........
But in my terminal I get something like `debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:07jcXlJ4SkBnyTmaVnmTpXuBiRx2+Q2adxbttO9gt0M`

I tried to pass that string inside 
`jSch.addIdentity()` method , but I get file not found exception.