# How to achieve port forwarding in android

Tags: android, ssh, jsch, portforwarding

I have created a web server in android, using [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) , I would like to forward this . If the server was running on a machine , then I can do it via ssh command like following

```
ssh -p 4000 -R test:80:localhost:1337 ssh.mydomain.net
```

I would like to do the exact same thing in android , I have explored a library called **[JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)** , but in all example it always requires an username and password . But as you can see , in the above command , there is no username or password required .

So my question is how can achieve this using **JSch** , or is there any other alternatives?

**Update**

This is what I have tried , but I got Algorithm negotiation fail exception

```
    String command ="ssh -p 4000 -R test:80:localhost:8080 test.ssh.domain.net";
    public void executeSSHcommand(){
        String user = "";
        String password = "";
        String host = "test.ssh.domain.net";
        int port=4000;
        try{

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setTimeout(10000);
            session.connect();
            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            channel.connect();
            //channel.disconnect();
        }
      catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what shall I use as `user` or `password`  or even `host` . As you can see , in the command there no username or password is required .

**Update 2**

I have also tried the following

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

But I get , **program ssh not found , permission denied**

Comment: same question was asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663771/how-to-run-ssh-command-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Yes I have seen , but no one answered that .

Comment: I recommend using public key authentication which is possible with jsch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html

Comment: I also guess, that your ssh command is already using publickey. Please verify in ssh -v output

Comment: It is not using any sorts of authentication .

Comment: Please run the ssh command with the "-v" flag to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output. This would give people a better idea of what ssh is really doing when it connects, and what you would have to do with jsch to get the same result.

Comment: The problem is , how can I possibly run this command in android ?

Comment: Just run the ssh command somewhere where it works.

Comment: @Kenster I have updated my question

Comment: as I said in your other question (now deleted), the provided code is confusing because you execute ssh command inside of another ssh session. Focus on the authentication by looking at the verbose output of your ssh command (outside of java)

Comment: Yes I have checked that , it accepts a public key , add some value in known hosts