# Keep getting Auth fail exception in JSch but I was able to ssh to IP without a password

Tags: java, jsch, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to create a JSch tunnel to ssh to an IP which is a passwordless setup to run a script. When I manually do an ssh to that IP, I don't need a password. `card.ipAddress` gives the IP address to ssh to and it is a passwordless setup. I have `log.info` (print) statements so I could know where exactly I was getting an exception. `remoteShellScript`has the path to the script.

```
            com.jcraft.jsch.Session jschSession = null;

            try {
                    log.info("Entering try block of JSch session");
                    JSch jsch = new JSch();
                    jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, card.ipAddress, REMOTE_PORT);
                    log.info("after getSession");

                    // not recommend, uses jsch.setKnownHosts
                    jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                    log.info("after setting Config");
                    // authenticate using password
                    //jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD);

                    // connect timeout session
                    jschSession.connect();                      //This is where I get the Exception
                    log.info("after connecting to jschSession");

                    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) jschSession.openChannel("exec");

                    log.info("Channel is open");

                    // run a shell script
                    channelExec.setCommand("sh " + remoteShellScript + "\"" + cn_ip + "\" "  + duration);
                    log.info("after running script");

                    // display errors to System.err
                    channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
                    log.info("after setErr");

                    //InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

                    // 5 seconds timeout channel
                    channelExec.connect();

                    log.info("after connect");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Catching exception", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    log.info("Disconnecting session from Finally block");
                    if (jschSession != null) {
                    jschSession.disconnect();
            }
```

**Exception:**

```
Catching exception: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

Comment: does passwordless mean, that you are using a key to authenticate or do you really mean without password? There was a question some time ago, where no password was needed, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663771/how-to-run-ssh-command-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

`Jsch` needs your key to be able to authenticate.

After:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
```

Add:

```
jsch.addIdentity( "path/to/your/key" );
```

Comment: The key is is in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` Should I enter it as `jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")` or `jsch.addIdentity(".ssh/id_rsa.pub")`. And when i open the .pub file, I see that `"ssh-rsa AGDGSOMERANDOMCHARACTERS root@some.host.name"` So, should I be picking the whole thing as a key? or are those randomcharacters the private key?

Comment: You need to write the path to your private key. The key must already be somewhere on the system you're running the code from (since you can manually connect without a problem).

Comment: Yeah isn't `"~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"` and `".ssh/id_rsa.pub"` considered paths? I don't know whether to include `~/` in the beginning or not.

Comment: sdasf: (1) _in a shell_ ~ is $HOME, but not in Java; if you run your program with working dir in $HOME, as is common, you can leave the directory out of the pathname (2) as Timon said, you need to provide the **private key file** -- that's `"path/.ssh/id_rsa"` NOT `"path/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`.